# How does this expression from the VQLS paper result in a CZ-gate?

Tags: vqe, terminology-and-notation

I am reading the [VQLS paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.05820) and equation C2 on page 10 they have:

$ \delta_{ll'}^j = \beta_{ll'} + \langle0|V^\dagger A_{l'}^\dagger U(Z_j \otimes I_\bar{j}) U^\dagger A_lV|0\rangle $

Here they define the $I_\bar{j}$ as "the identity on all qubits except qubit $j$" (see the text below equation 7).

They then go on to say that equation C2 can be calculated from the circuit in Fig.9c (reproduced below).

[image]
I understand how the circuit is made except for the $CZ$ gate. Is it the case that $(Z_j \otimes I_\bar{j}) = CZ$ and if so, can you demonstrate how this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They perform a [Hadamard Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_test_(quantum_computation)):

[image: Hadamard-Test circuit]

with

$$
\vert \psi \rangle = V(\alpha)\vert 0 \rangle
$$

and:

$$
M = A_{l'}^\dagger U (Z_j\otimes I_{\overline{j}}) U^\dagger A_l
$$

By replacing the expression of $M$ in the circuit, you end up with the circuit you provided **except** that the two $U$ are controlled. "Removing" the controls here is a simplification that can be performed because $U$ and $U^\dagger$ simplify to the identity. To convince yourself about this:

1. If the control qubit is $\vert 0 \rangle$ then the $M$ is not applied. By removing the controls from the $U$ and $U^\dagger$, they are both applied (because they are no more controlled) but they "cancel" each other so the final operation is the identity, as expected.
2. If the control qubit is $\vert 1 \rangle$ then $U$ and $U^\dagger$ are supposed to be applied too, which is the case.

So the controlled-$Z$ comes from the fact that the whole $M$ gate is controlled, which means that each of the gates that compose $M$ will be controlled too, $Z$ being one of them.

Comment: @thespaceman,  Obviously, I am new to this.   Could you give me some intuition why local cost function has Z and can replace 0><0 from the global cost?

Comment: @JohnParker, The ```Z``` gate comes from the identity $|0_j\rangle\langle0_j|=(I_j+Z_j)/2$. This is discussed in the VQLS paper just above equation (C2) in the appendix. Unfortunately, I cannot provide any intuition as to why the local cost function has a ```Z``` gate as I am new to the field myself. The only discussion that I have found in this paper is the text surrounding equation (6), but they really just state the Hamiltonian used without explaining it.

Comment: The talk of Patrick Coles at QHack2021 might be a good start to understand. I'm linking a specific timestamp where he starts talking about global VS local cost, but the whole video is worth looking at: https://youtu.be/bwmLfxelwUA?t=665