# Variational Quantum Linear Solver (Hadamard test): circuit question

Tags: quantum-algorithms, vqe, linear-algebra

Trying to understand the circuit/algorithm for VQLS and I found this diagram to show the high-level idea of doing the Hadamard test in [this](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_vqls.html) tutorial. But I am not quite sure why we need the two circuit blocks in the red box that I drew.

[image]

I appreciate the insight.

Comment: Can you share the link from where you found that image so people can look at it and answer your questions more easily?

Comment: From the first glance, it looks like an uncomputation step(see that it is the exact inverse of block 2 and block 3) so as to restore the all 0 state of the ancilla register but as @epelaaez said, source of that image would be pretty helpful.

Comment: @epelaaez just added the link .  Thanks

Comment: I think I answered this here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16934/1386. It might not be a full answer, this question is not really a duplicate, but it might be enough to fill the gap. Tell me if this does not answer your question.

Comment: @Andrien Suau    Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This circuit is used to calculate the coefficients $\mu_{l, l', j}$ which appear in the numerator of $C_
L$

\begin{align*}\mu_{l, l', j} = \langle 0|  V^\dagger A_{l'}^\dagger U Z_j U^\dagger A_l  V |0\rangle\end{align*}

Hadamard test is used to calculate the expectation value $\langle\psi|{\bf Q}|\psi\rangle$.

Now we have,

$$\langle\psi|{\bf Q}|\psi\rangle\ = \langle 0|  V^\dagger (A_{l'}^\dagger U Z_j U^\dagger A_l)  V |0\rangle$$

That is, $|\psi\rangle\ = V |0\rangle$ and ${\bf Q} = A_{l'}^\dagger U Z_j U^\dagger A_l$.

Comment: Thank you so much  Both of you  Very clear!  Salute!

Comment: But why do you need to control $A$ but not $U$ (here I refer to $U$ as the blue box of the circuit)? I thought that in a Hadamard test you need to control all the unitaries used to encode $U$ (here by $U$ I mean the general unitary in your answer)

Comment: @Enrico, You are correct in assuming that the $U$ should be controlled. However, it is also equivalent not to include the control. See Adrien Suau's answer in this question for an explanation: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16931/how-does-this-expression-from-the-vqls-paper-result-in-a-cz-gate

Comment: @thespaceman Thanks for the link, it makes perfect sense!

Comment: @Egretta.Thula  Follow-up question on calculating the expectation value. $$\langle\psi|{\bf Q}|\psi\rangle\ = \langle 0|  V^\dagger (A_{l'}^\dagger U Z_j U^\dagger A_l)  V |0\rangle$$    I assume this is done in Z (standard) basis or do we have to do transformation based on the matrix A , similar to VQE, to measure the expectation value?